# Download all pdf files using wget

Tags: wget

I have the following site http://www.asd.com.tr. I want to download all PDF files into one directory. I've tried a couple of commands but am not having much luck.

```
$ wget --random-wait -r -l inf -nd -A pdf http://www.asd.com.tr/
```

With this code only four PDF files were downloaded. Check this link, there are over several thousand PDFs available:

- http://www.asd.com.tr/Default.aspx

For instance, hundreds of files are in the following folder:

- http://www.asd.com.tr/Folders/asd/…

But I can't figure out how to access them correctly to see and download them all, there are some of folders in this subdirectory, http://www.asd.com.tr/Folders/, and thousands of PDFs in these folders.

I've tried to mirror site using `-m` command but it failed too.

Any more suggestions?

Comment: I'm just trying to do examples for wget and i'm turkish guy and this site is very popular.. that's it. no offence bro..

Answer (score 9):

First, verify that the TOS of the web site permit to crawl it. Then, one solution is :

```
mech-dump --links 'http://domain.com' |
    grep pdf$ |
    sed 's/\s+/%20/g' |
    xargs -I% wget http://domain.com/%
```

The `mech-dump` command comes with Perl's module `WWW::Mechanize` (`libwww-mechanize-perl` package on debian & debian likes distros)