# Can't download all files from a directory using wget

Tags: linux, download, wget

I'm trying to download all the pdf files from a directory using `wget` using this command:

```
  wget -r -A pdf http://website/~subfolder/
```

With this command, I can download only some files. I know there are more pdf files inside because I can reach them using google. I took a look here:

[Download all pdf files using wget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19883073/download-all-pdf-files-using-wget)

but the solution doesn't work for me. Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Are the files are located in subfolders?

Comment: try this  `wget -r -A "*.pdf" http://website/~subfolder/`

Comment: With your command i obtain the same output. It's very strange because if i search the docs on google i can find them, and they're located in the same subfolder.

Comment: UPDATE: i can see all the files thanks to google. The command to insert in the searchbar is: filetype:pdf site:http://website/~subfolder/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to download HTTP directory with all files and sub-directories as they appear on the online files/folders list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446635/how-to-download-http-directory-with-all-files-and-sub-directories-as-they-appear)